# RxAndroidBLE BleGattException when autoconnect=true

Tags: rxandroidble

I'm getting BleGattException with status 19 after a while when observing notifications on connection established with autoconnect=true. According to [this source](http://allmydroids.blogspot.com.by/2015/06/android-ble-error-status-codes-explained.html) it means that BLE device has forced a disconnect. As it usually happens in about 30sec after last notification received I assume that device just goes to sleep. However it seems that in this case there shouldn't be any exceptions for specified type of connection... Please, advise what might be the reason of such a behaviour?

Comment: Do you use a Nexus 5 perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the official Bluetooth standard that error code means "The Remote User Terminated Connection error code indicates that the user on the remote device terminated the connection."

So if you wonder why the remote end disconnects after 30 seconds you must ask the one who developed that peripheral to find out why.